# why eclipse not detect the jar file from lib folder

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I am trying to develop java desktop application using eclipse and using some external jar file in project.

I have put that all jar file in `/lib` folder (this is desktop application so here `/WEB-INF` does not exist)  now the problem is that the application cannot detect external jar file what is the problem ? and how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add external jar file as :-

```
  Click Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries.
    Click Add External Jars and browse to the JAR file that contains the look and feel, then click OK. 
Now, you are ready to apply the new Look and Feel to your application.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have add it to classpath as well. right click on project and click add to build project.
click libraries tab and click external jar files. select your jar files. It will be added to classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to inserti it. Rightclick in project properties build path, add external jar and browser to it.

Answer (score 0):

just put jar file into the **libs** folder and abb to build path thats it. Updated eclipse not getting jar or configure file from the lib they get jar file from the libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on your jar file and choose `Build Path` and then choose `add to build path`